# Number of objects in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I was wondering if there was any possible way to get the number (count) of objects in an NSArray Object

Comment: +1 I guess first thing to look for is NSArray docs and search for word 'count' ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You bet! From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

```
NSUInteger numObjects = [myArray count];
```

Comment: You're welcome. In future, it may be easier (and quicker) to look these things up in the documentation. Apple has an extensive reference library which can come in very handy, especially for the basics of how the built-in classes work. I don't want to discourage you from asking questions, though. Just a productivity tip to keep in mind for next time. Have fun with your code :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes: `int count = [array count];`

Comment: Try to use `NSUInteger` instead of `int`.